# Android UI not Updating programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

I am writing this following code.. but some parts are working and some are not working, I can't figure out why..

**These are working fine**

```
    ScrollView deviceList = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.deviceManager);
    deviceList.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    TableLayout deviceTable = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    deviceTable.setId(951357);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tr.setLayoutParams(layout);
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText("Searching");
    tv.setVisibility(1);
    tr.addView(tv);
    deviceTable.addView(tr);
    deviceList.addView(deviceTable);
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    deviceTable.removeAllViews();
    LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setLayoutParams(layout);
    tr.setLayoutParams(layout);
    tv.setText("No more devices");
    if(rowCounter%2==0)
    {
        System.out.println("rowCounter%2==0");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("rowCounter%2==1");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
```

**Not Working**

```
    tv.setVisibility(1);
    tv.setEnabled(true);
    tr.addView(tv);
    tr.setVisibility(1);
    deviceTable.addView(tr);
```

**Again Working**

```
    System.out.println(tv+" "+tr+" "+deviceTable+" "+tv.getText());
    deviceTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    System.out.println("No more devices");
```

**EDIT:**

```
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tv.setEnabled(true);
tr.addView(tv);
tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
deviceTable.addView(tr);
System.out.println(tv+" "+tr+" "+deviceTable+" "+tv.getText());
deviceTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
System.out.println("No more devices");
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working

Comment: TextView should appear... but it is not appearing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error with:

```
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayout(layout);
```

The Error is:

```
The TableRow Layout Params being applied to TextView.
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

instead of

```
tr.setVisibility(1);
```

note that View.VISIBLE 's constant value is 0 not 1. So if you set 1 then you will not get proper result. So instead of using int always use `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.GONE`. It will both increase readability and will reduce chance of error

Comment: but it is working fine above.. and I have been using this code from a long time.

Comment: can you please check this with visible

Comment: it should work .. have you tried to set all visilibility to View.Visible?? please post your updated code